# Laravel 4 difference between URL::asset() and asset()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

For loading assets in Laravel 4 projects there is a [helper](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls) to create a URL for an asset

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" />
```

But that helper could be called using a facade too

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}" />
```

which produce the same result.

So my question is, which is the real difference here, one way is better in terms of performance than the other or is just a preference style ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the `asset()` function:

```php
if ( ! function_exists('asset'))
{
    /**
     * Generate an asset path for the application.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @param  bool    $secure
     * @return string
     */
    function asset($path, $secure = null)
    {
        return app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
    }
}
```

Both of the functions are, therefore, the same. `asset()` is simply a helper function. Specifically, helpers are more appropriate for views. So, yes, it is a preference thing. I tend to prefer using Facades.

Answer (score 2):

they are the same. the helper function is just an alias.

Comment: So, asset() is actually calling the facade ??

Comment: Not the Facade, necessarily. See my answer. That code can be found in `<laravel-project-root>/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php`